# Problema al importar dict desde un módulo

Tags: python, python-import

Tengo un problema con los imports en una aplicación. Tengo un módulo que controla las strings de salida del programa (es un programa bilingüe) llamado main_Global.py. En él tengo varios dicts (msg, errs, entre otros), los cuales son asignados dependiendo del lenguaje que se elija al principio. El resto del programa puede ejecutar todo a la perfección. Cuando intento agregar nuevos diccionarios ('conf_descriptions' se llama el que quiero agregar) salta NameError, como si no existiese. Dicho esto, probé con otros nombres. Mismo problema. Intenté otras sintaxis de import (From import..., import, import as...) y no me reconoce nuevos diccionarios. También probé llamarlo a modo de prueba al principio del módulo justo después del import, por si hubiera un error en mi código ajeno a esto, y lo mismo. Estoy usando Python 3.8.4, por si sirve de algo. Todos los módulos están en el mismo directorio.

```
from main_Global import *
print(debug) #Estos dos diccionarios están contiguos en main_Global, en el mismo bloque. Este se imprime
print(conf_descriptions) #Este callea NameError
NameError: name 'conf_descriptions' is not defined
```

Comment: Probaste `from main_Global import conf_descriptions` ?

Comment: abulafia. Lo acabé de probar. Me tira ImportError: cannot import name 'conf_descriptions' from 'main_Global' (C:..\main_Global.py)

Comment: En ese caso... ¿puedes pegar la parte del código donde defines ese símbolo a ver si se observa algo raro? Sospecho que el nombre no sea exactamente como lo estás tecleando.

Comment: Acabé de probar printeando el dict apenas lo defino, en el mismo módulo. Probé también pegarlo en el módulo del cual yo quiero referenciar, y funcionaba perfecto el code. Al hacer control Z en ambos archivos, sigue tirando el mismo error.

Comment: Error mío. Estaba intentando callear un dict dentro de una función. Faltaba la declaración de Global dentro de ésta.